# SQL: Select criteria for two tables, compare 1 field, return using condition

Tags: sql

These are the tables in the query. Want to compare the ID_Skills in the following 2 tables. And in the returning table from the select query, display ID_Skills with condition saying whether or not TrainingRequired (Yes/No)

**tblEmployeeCurrentSkills**

```
ID_EmployeeCurrentSkills  ID_Employee   ID_Skills
           1               1            1
           2               1            2
           3               2            1
```

**tblSkillsRequired**

```
ID_SkillsRequired  ID_Employee   ID_Skills     ID_Position
    1               1            1               1
    2               1            2               1
    3               1            3               1
    4               2            3               2
```

**tblSkills**

```
ID_Skills        Skill
    1           Reading
    2           Wiring
    3           Stapling
```

**tblPosition**

```
ID_Position         Position
     1                Tech1
     2                Stapler
```

**tblEmployee**

```
  ID_Employee      EmployeeName
       1               Hannah
       2                 Bob
```

**SQL for qrySkillsGap table - determines whether training is necessary**

```
SELECT tblEmployee.[Employee Name], 
tblSkillsRequired.ID_Skills, 
tblSkills.Skill, 
IIf([tblEmployeeCurrentSkills].[ID_Skills] 
Like [tblSkillsRequired].[ID_Skills],"No","Yes") AS TrainingRequired

FROM (tblSkills 
INNER JOIN tblSkillsRequired 
ON tblSkills.ID_Skills = tblSkillsRequired.ID_Skills) 
INNER JOIN (tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblEmployeeCurrentSkills 
ON tblEmployee.ID_Employee = tblEmployeeCurrentSkills.ID_Employee) 
ON tblSkills.ID_Skills = tblEmployeeCurrentSkills.ID_Skills;
```

This is the current output:

```
 EmployeeName      ID_Skill          TrainingRequired
     Hannah           1                     No
     Hannah           1                     No
     Hannah           2                     No
       Bob            1                     No
       Bob            1                     No
```

I want it to display this:

```
 EmployeeName      ID_Skill          TrainingRequired
     Hannah           1                     No
     Hannah           2                     No
     Hannah           3                     Yes
       Bob            1                     No
       Bob            3                     Yes
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to create the tables you provided and used a union to bring together the employee skills and required skills.

```
SELECT  te.EmployeeName
      , emp.ID_Skills
      , CASE WHEN MIN(emp.TrainingRequired) = 0 THEN 'No'
             ELSE 'Yes'
        END AS TrainingRequired
FROM    dbo.tblEmployee AS te
JOIN    (SELECT tecs.ID_Employee
              , tecs.ID_Skills
              , 0 AS TrainingRequired
         FROM   dbo.tblEmployeeCurrentSkills AS tecs
         UNION
         SELECT tsr.ID_Employee
              , tsr.ID_Skills
              , 1 AS TrainingRequired
         FROM   dbo.tblSkillsRequired AS tsr
        ) emp
        ON te.ID_Employee = emp.ID_Employee
GROUP BY te.ID_Employee
      , te.EmployeeName
      , emp.ID_Skills
ORDER BY te.ID_Employee
      , emp.ID_Skills
```